# Google Product search

Tags: iphone, product

How to get nearby stores for a product using google Product search API ?

I had input parameters as ....

- Latitude
- Longitude
- Product Name

Can u please give the Request URL..... 
For implementing it on iPhone

Also how to get reviews for a product using google product search
Can u please give the Request URL.....

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The most current Products API is the [Search API for Shopping](http://code.google.com/apis/shopping/search/v1/getting_started.html). It does not allow you to query by physical location, but it does allow you to search by a product name.

You'll need to [get an API key](http://code.google.com/apis/console) to use the API, but when you do, the request URL will be like:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/shopping/search/v1/public/products?country=US&q=macbook%20pro&alt=json&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Comment: Thanks dude, I got this and also implemented.... but now searching for physical address of stores in which product is available.... I got all the links for online stores.....but my next step is to get nearby stores.... thanks for your response